# Allow to see the rejection reason the previous user chose

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

It would help if I could see the rejection reason already selected from other user in the dialog box that I see when I choose to reject a suggested edit; it would be similar to what happen when I vote to close a question, and other users already voted to close the same question.

[image: screenshot]

For example, if the suggested edit has been rejected as minor edit, and I didn't notice anything wrong with the it, I can check again the edit, and verify if effectively the edit just correct less things than it should.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has now been implemented in the same way as for close votes:

[image]

---

You can see the rejection reason if you click on the "permalink to this edit suggestion" link.

The rejection reason is displayed in the "Reviewer stats" section under the suggested edit.

[image]

But I agree that having it work like the close vote dialog would be a bit more practical.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for this. My [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130301/can-the-reject-reason-be-more-prominent) suggested either showing the rejection reason when you hover over the "Reject" button, or showing something like this (inspired from the 10k flag queue);

[image]

My reasoning behind this was because you want to see the other reason *before* casting your vote.

On the other-hand, when you're voting to close a question you've more than likely *already* decided why you want to close it; if you had to click the "Reject" button to bring up the popup to see the rejected-reason, you'd end up closing the popup to double check whether the initial vote was correct first.

Either way, any improvement on the current UI would be welcomed!