# Clearer statement of rejection reason in some circumstances

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review, rejection-reasons

I know that you can view the rejection/acceptance information for an edit when you click on a permalink; however, in some circumstances, would it be reasonable for some of this to be stated in the main edit screen as well?

For example: I was reviewing and found that a suggested edit for the [multiprocessing](/questions/tagged/multiprocessing) tag was a copy from the Wikipedia page of the same name (see my related question, [Reviewing Edits - what counts as plagiarism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114312/reviewing-edits-what-counts-as-plagiarism))

In this case (i.e. plagiarism) it may not be noticed by reviewers, and the edit be accepted. While the information is visible through the permalink, it is very possible that reviewers won't look at this, and just accept the edit.

Obviously we can add the citation ourselves, but this won't teach the editor that the citation needs to be there for the next edit he makes.

Any thoughts?

Update: To emphasise my point, the multiprocessing tag edit has now been approved without citation.

Comment: This would be a great case to have [the 'Reject and Improve' button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83721/148310).  The reviewer could smack down the thieving edit and fix it at the same time.

Comment: I'll think about it, my reservation with making a feature request in the first place was that I didn't want to pre-empt what the solution should be, rather I just wanted to highlight an area that users find difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe if one of the reviewers rejects it for "copied content" (plagiarism), then ***one or more*** of the following occurs:

1. Before another user can accept or "improve" the edit, a confirmation dialog appears, saying something like, "Another user has found that this content is plagiarized. Please confirm that this is not the case before accepting this edit."
2. <strike>Only, say, 5K users can approve such edits.</strike>
   Alas, [the *Suggested Edit* record, where this plagiarism was accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/148637), shows that this would be ineffective. Both approving users were over 10K.
3. An automatic system flag gets kicked to the 10K tools, if an edit is ultimately accepted after being rejected for "copied content".
   10K users can confirm or dispute, just like the current flags.

Comment: +1 - Good ideas. I even thought of just having a comment/message similar to the one when you flag a post as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

The rejection reason should be shown in the review page whatever reason has been selected.

[image: screenshot]

As alternative, I proposed that the rejection dialog box would show the reason selected by the previous user in [Allow to see the rejection reason the previous user chose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108534/allow-to-see-the-rejection-reason-selected-from-the-previous-user-in-the-rejecti).

The problem with the suggested edits for tag wikis is that you can only approve, or reject the proposed edit. In the case it should necessary to add a link (or improve the edit in any other way), you can just wait the proposed edit is rejected or approved, and then propose another edit; there isn't a way for you to improve the currently proposed edit, and let somebody else approve the improved edit.
If this would be possible, you could improve a suggested edit to remove the part that is not acceptable, or to add a part without the which the proposed edit is not acceptable.