# Show edit suggestion results more clearly

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, design, rejected-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow to see the rejection reason selected from the previous user in the rejection dialog box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108534/allow-to-see-the-rejection-reason-selected-from-the-previous-user-in-the-rejecti)

When reviewing, it's pretty dang hard to understand why a fellow reviewer had reject an edit suggestion. (And it's even harder if you happen to come by the post and see the edit was rejected).

Currently, you need to go to the edit suggestion permalink, scroll down past the list of changes, and find the reviewer results section, to tell you why the suggestion was rejected.

Is it not possible to have something similar to the vote system, that when someone rejects an edit a small number (or flag, or whatever) would appear next to the reason of the rejection?

Not something I think would improve the overall hyper efficiency of the site, but still, it would be a nice addition to the GUI.

Comment: I actually knew that SOMEONE had to post it before I did, but I honestly couldn't find it. [meta-tag:cv-pls].