# Show previous reject reason for suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow to see the rejection reason the previous user chose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108534/allow-to-see-the-rejection-reason-the-previous-user-chose)

I'd like to see that an edit was already rejected by another reviewer and especially the reason for this decision. Right now, in the new beta-review you can't even see whether an edit was approved or rejected previously (in the old review view the buttons had `(1)` when someone else already made a decision).

The problem is, that some reject decisions are not obvious. Simple example: copied content. I google for every suggested tag edit and very often it is copied without proper attribution. However, a few minutes later I find the edit approved by two other reviewers.
I am sure that they would have rejected, too, if they just had the information that someone else already thinks that the content is copied. Or at least they would have checked the content more carefully themselves.
And with individual rejections (where someone enters free text) it is even more important to show the text to other reviewers.

**EDIT:**
I'd like to see this information on the review page. Not hidden in a popup. When a edit is marked as copied content for example, every following reviewer should be aware of it instantly.

Comment: On the other hand there is something to be said for the "blind" review as well. I'd rather see people come to their individual decisions than be influenced by the decisions of others. Although sometimes the result is admittedly frustrating. Perhaps only an exception could be made for copied content?

Comment: @Brad Mace: this question is not a duplicate. I am not asking for a notification in the reject popup, but for one on the review page. Please reopen - the problem still exists!

Answer (score 2):

If you click reject, you get a window where you can chose the reject reason.

If there was a previous reject vote, it is shown there.

Comment: But at least the free text is not shown. And should I click on reject every time now, just to see previous decisions?

Comment: Here is a great example, especially made for and by you ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/350488 (possible source is http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/, but there is no attribution)